# Anyone using Salesforce Functions to read and write via SFTP?

Tags: integration, ftp, sftp, salesforce-functions

Trying to figure out whether to look further into using [Salesforce Functions](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/342960/salesforce-functions-use-cases) to read and write and also transform large documents via SFTP.

Three barriers to this are:

- The pricing - not cheap: see the Elastic Services section of the [Salesforce Add-on Pricing](https://www.salesforce.com/content/dam/web/en_us/www/documents/pricing/all-add-ons.pdf).
- A license is needed to turn on in our PBO.
- The investment of time learning how to use them.

So interested in learning from any relevant experience anyone has had with them before burning time on this...

(We have other uses for Salesforce Functions on our roadmap, but this is the first thing to come up so wondering if a good fit or not.)